# How to combine Plot and GeoGraphics?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to combine this map as "background" of this combined plot.
How can I do it?
The documentation doesn't show any similar demonstration.

```
GeoGraphics[ GeoRange -> "World", GeoBackground -> Automatic, 
             GeoProjection -> {"Orthographic", "Centering" -> GeoPosition[{90, 0}]},
             AspectRatio -> 1/2]

Show[ 
  ParametricPlot[{R Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
                  PlotStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.75, 0.75, 0.75]]], 
  ListPlot[ Table[{{R Cos[t], r Sin[t]}}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/24}], 
            PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Orange]], 
  Axes -> False, Frame -> False, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> Full, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

Comment: what value of R, and r?

Answer (score 9):

```
geo =
 GeoGraphics[GeoRange -> "World",
  GeoBackground -> Automatic,
  GeoProjection -> {"Orthographic", "Centering" -> GeoPosition[{90, 0}]},
  Axes->True,
  AspectRatio -> 1/2];

plo =
 ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  AspectRatio -> 1/2];

Show[Graphics @@ geo, plo, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]